# Check with selenium tests, if all this divs has text

Tags: java, selenium, testing

This is modal window, and I need to check 
check if all fields are filled.

```
 <div _ngcontent-c6="" class="modal-body">
    <div _ngcontent-c6="" class="row">
    <div _ngcontent-c6="" class="col-12 bg-termin_ztv">Wichtig</div>
    </div>
    <br _ngcontent-c6="">
    <div _ngcontent-c6="" class="row">
    <div _ngcontent-c6="" class="col-2"> AD: </div>
    <div _ngcontent-c6="" class="col-10">
    <span _ngcontent-c6="">Arnemann, Marcus</span><span _ngcontent-c6=""> (beschäftigt)</span>
    </div>
    </div>
    <br _ngcontent-c6="">
    <div _ngcontent-c6="" class="row">
    <div _ngcontent-c6="" class="col-2"> Anfang: </div>
    <div _ngcontent-c6="" class="col-3"> 23.10.2018 </div>
    <div _ngcontent-c6="" class="col-7"> 09:00 </div>
    </div>
    <br _ngcontent-c6="">
    <div _ngcontent-c6="" class="row">
    <div _ngcontent-c6="" class="col-2"> Ende: </div>
    <div _ngcontent-c6="" class="col-3"> 23.10.2018 </div>
    <div _ngcontent-c6="" class="col-7"> 01:00 </div>
    </div>
    <br _ngcontent-c6="">
    <div _ngcontent-c6="" class="row">
    <div _ngcontent-c6="" class="col-2"> Ort: </div>
    <div _ngcontent-c6="" class="col-10"> Musterstraße 13, 12345 Musterstadt </div></div>
    <br _ngcontent-c6="">
    <div _ngcontent-c6="" class="row">
    <div _ngcontent-c6="" class="col-12"> Hallo Herr Tilsner,
                    'Wir haben für Sie einen Termin vereinbart. </div>
    </div>
    <br _ngcontent-c6="">
    </div>
```

I tried this:

```
     modalBody = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tm-termin-anzeige [contains(@class, 'modal-body')]").getText());
     assertTrue(modalBody.getEventElements().size() > 0);
```

It works, but not good. I have returned true if just one letter is available. And I can't give some id to every field. Because it's generated dynamically with Angular.

Answer (score 0):

All div elements nested after div with class row

```
//div[@class='modal-body']/div[@class='row']/descendant::div
```

as i see they only have a text, this was your issue ?

Getting the count of elements without text:

```
List<WebElement> allelements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class=\'modal-body\']/div[@class=\'row\']/descendant::div"));
long withouttext = allelements.stream().filter(e -> !e.getText().isEmpty()).count();
```

Comment: No, actually I need to check if all div which not nested has some text

Comment: can you clarify, what exactly you need since the xpath i provided is locating all div elements with text from the sample you provided.

Comment: I need to check if between div is some text exist, like beetween <div _ngcontent-c6="" class="col-2">  AD: </div>. I have: "AD:"

Comment: how the answer, does not provide such verification?

Answer (score 0):

You can try script like below.

```
  IWebElement WebElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tm-termin-anzeige [contains(@class, 'modal-body')]"));
  IList<IWebElement> AllTexts = WebElement.FindElements(By.XPath("//div"));

  int RowCount = AllTexts.Count;
  for (int i = 0; i < RowCount; i++)
        {
         AllTexts[i].getText();
// You can improve here like "if there is no text give me element" because not all divs has text under modal-body 
        }
```